# How design left menu panel

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

in windows wpf i want design a left bar menu like this:

[image]

when i click on an item, in the right the window change.
With which control can i design this?

- Tab bar control?
- Or a left dock panel and insert inside it some button? In this case how can I change the window on the right when click on a button?

Comment: Have you worked with MVVM & messenger classes?

Comment: Looks like a `TabControl` to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each time you click on a button you want to display a different view, you could define each of your views in a separate control and in your main window within a grid declare each view in a DockPanel.

Then by binding the visibility property of each DockPanel you can create the logic in order to display only what you want on each click.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a styled `ListBox` and binding the `Visibility` property of your content to it. Even better you can also use a styled `Tab` control.